# What is "fbmeshd"?

Tags: facebook, github, server

I was wondering what fbmeshd is, as they haven't written it on their GitHub.
Here's their repo on GitHub: https://github.com/facebook/fbmeshd

Comment: What makes you think this had anything to do with hosting websites? This is about building “Self-organizing Mesh Access” networks with WiFi devices.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fbmeshd is about building “Self-organizing Mesh Access” networks with WiFi devices.